# viso2_ros and robot_pose_ekf

Tags: ros, navigation, viso2-ros, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

Is there any way to get the visual odometry from the viso2_ros package to the robot_pose_ekf. From what I have had a look , the robot_pose_ekf requires data on the /vo topic. Is the data coming out of visi2_ros can be published on the /vo and fed into the robot_pose_ekf??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34323/viso2_ros-and-robot_pose_ekf/) by [rohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2278/rohan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 358 on 2012-05-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yes, just hook up the viso2_ros/odometry to the robot_pose_ekf/vo since they are both nav_msgs/Odometry messages.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1